# raspbian samba write issues

Tags: raspbian

I followed [this](http://cymplecy.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/treating-a-raspberrypi-as-just-another-windows-machine-4-2/) tutorial to install samba on my PI, but I can not write to the files?

my smb.conf:

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = mypi server
netbios name = mypi
 
dns proxy = no
 
#### Debugging/Accounting ####
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
 
####### Authentication #######
security = user
map to guest = pi
 
#======================= Share Definitions =======================
[homes]
 
comment = Home Directories
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
writeable = yes
guest account = pi
 
[public]
path = /
guest ok = yes
guest account = ftp
browseable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
writeable = yes
admin users = everyone
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out!

as root I had to change the file permissions, and then I was able to write to my PI!

[screenshot](http://qs.lc/8vqx9)